# How to handle a Hibernate multi-field search query on nullable child entities

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Using Spring Boot Web & Data JPA (2.3.1) with QueryDSL with PostgreSQL 11, we are trying to implement a custom search for a UI table on an entity with two `@ManyToOne` child entities. The idea is to be able to provide a single search input field and search for that string (`like` or `contains` ignore case) across multiple String fields across the entities' fields and also provide paging. During UI POCs, we were originally pulling the entire list and having the web UI provide this exact search functionality but that will not be sustainable in the future.

My original thought was something to this effect:

```
/devices?externalId={{val}}&site.externalId={{val}}&organization.name={{val}}&size=10
```

but the more human readable intent was:

```
externalId={{val}} OR site.externalId={{val}} OR organization.name={{val}} WITH size=10
```

I tried implementing it with QueryDSL's Web Bindings (hence the above example) with a `QuerydslBinderCustomizer` but it didn't work. Then I realized that it doesn't provide much for this particular situation so I moved to a JpaRepository with an `@Query` and shortened the URL to.

```
/devices?search={{val}}&size=10
```

Either way, what seems to be happening is that if, for example, `device.site` is null, the entire result is always zero. Even if `device.organization` or `device.site` is null, I would expect results where the `device.externalId` matches the search value criteria. If I remove support for `site.externalId`, then it works; I get results matching the `device.externalId`. I also tried this on a database with `devices` with non-null `site` references and that also worked. So the issue seems to be centered around null child entities.

### Quick Scenario:

**Note:** Device in JSON format and id's in non-UUID format for brevity.

```
   {
      "id" : "a",
      "externalId" : "VTD1002",
      "site" : null
   },
   {
      "id" : "b",
      "externalId" : "VTD_1000",
      "site" : { "externalId" : "VTS_1000" }
   },
   {
      "id" : "c",
      "externalId" : "VFD_1000"
      "site" : { "externalId" : "VFS_1000" }
   }
```

Pseudo Tests:

1. search = "t" -> resulting IDs = a, b

- Only `a` and `b` have a `T`

2. search = "Z" -> resulting IDs =

- None have `Z`

3. search = "1" -> resulting IDs = a, b, c

- All have a `1`

4. search = "2" -> resulting IDs = a

- Only `a` has a `2`

### Entities

**Note:** redacted from original for brevity

```
@Entity
@Data @Builder
@Table(name = "devices")
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = "id")
@NoArgsConstructor @AllArgsConstructor
public class Device {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private UUID id;

    private String externalId;

    @ManyToOne
    private Product product;

    @ManyToOne
    private Site site;


}
```

```
@Entity
@Data @Builder
@Table(name = "organizations")
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = "id")
@NoArgsConstructor @AllArgsConstructor
public class Organization {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private UUID id;

    private String name;
 
    @ToString.Exclude
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "organization")
    private Set<Device> devices;

}
```

```
@Entity
@Data @Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = "id")
@Table(name = "sites")
public class Site {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private UUID id;

    private String externalId;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "site")
    private Set<Device> devices;

}
```

Here's the latest I've tried without luck:

```
@Query("from Device d where (d.externalId like lower(:search)) or (d.site.id is not null and d.site.externalId like lower(:search)) or (d.organization.id is not null and d.organization.externalId like lower(:search))")
Page<Device> search(String search, Pageable pageable);
```

The idea was to check for the device's `site_id` reference on the table before even trying to evaluate the `Site`'s `externalId`. Removing the `is not null` didn't make a difference and going `d.site is not null` also didn't work.

I think what's happening is that the native SQL that is generated is causing things to go awry.  I suspect the issue is in the `cross joins` but after a few days of searching, any clues or insights would be appreciated.

```
    select
        device0_.id as id1_3_,
        device0_.external_id as external3_3_,
        device0_.organization_id as organiz13_3_,
        device0_.site_id as site_id15_3_,
    from
        devices device0_ cross             
    join
        sites site1_ cross 
    join
        organizations organizati2_ 
    where
        device0_.site_id=site1_.id 
        and device0_.organization_id=organizati2_.id 
        and (
            device0_.external_id like lower(?) 
            or (
                device0_.site_id is not null
            ) 
            and (
                site1_.external_id like lower(?)
            ) 
            or (
                device0_.organization_id is not null
            ) 
            and (
                organizati2_.external_id like lower(?)
            )
        ) limit ?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem as you can see is that Hibernate uses inner joins for your implicit joins, which is forced onto it by JPA. Having said that, you will have to use left joins like this to make this null-aware stuff work

```
@Query("from Device d left join d.site s left join d.organization o where (d.externalId like lower(:search)) or (s.id is not null and s.externalId like lower(:search)) or (o.id is not null and o.externalId like lower(:search))")
Page<Device> search(String search, Pageable pageable);
```

Comment: Thanks @christian-beikov.With your suggestion, I was able to compare the generated native sql's with both approaches, experiment and see where I went wrong. I ended up having to enhance the final query a bit more to get it to work. I'll detail in a comment. Thank you for the quick response.

Answer (score 0):

With @christian-beikov help, I was able to get pass the nullability piece. However, I had to modify the query to get it working all the way through to the web controller.

```
    @Query("select d from Device d left join d.site s left join d.organization o "
            + "where lower(d.externalId) like concat('%', lower(:search),'%')"
            + "or lower(s.externalId) like concat('%', lower(:search),'%')"
            + "or lower(o.externalId) like concat('%', lower(:search),'%')")
    Page<Device> focusedSearchByValue(String search, Pageable pageable);
```

1. I had to add `select d` so that I would get back a list of `Devices` and not of `Object`.
2. I then had to make sure both the search term and the target column value of  were in lower-case so that the comparison is "apples to apples".
3. Finally, I added the equivalent of `ilike %{search}%` because apparently there is no HQL support for `ilike`.

As a side note, for experimentation purposes, I also looked at what this equivalent approach generated to further explore the problem.

```
Page<Device> findAllByExternalIdContainsOrSiteExternalIdContainsOrOrganizationNameContains(String v1, String v2, String v3, Pageable pageable);
```